# column context menu checkbox toggle in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, ag-grid

I am trying to add the context menu checkbox for whole column in ag-grid.
By following [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#customising-the-general-menu-tab) tutorial I was able to add a checkbox to my custom menu by setting `checked : true` but this is not a togglable checkbox. it is always set to true only. How to make it togglable?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to define the context of the grid options as follows: **context: { thisComponent: this }**

```
public gridOptions: any = {
   columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
   rowData: this.rowData,
   enableSorting: false,
   enableFilter: false,
   context: { thisComponent: this }
}
```

Then you have to create your own function which returns true or false:

```
public checkedContextMenuFunction(params): boolean {
   if (){
       return true;
   }else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

and add it to the contextMenuItems function:

**checked: params.context.thisComponent.checkedContextMenuFunction(params)**

```
public getContextMenuItems(params) {
  return{      
     'separator',
     {
       name: 'Checked menu',
       tooltip: 'Tooltip text',
       checked: params.context.thisComponent.checkedContextMenuFunction(params),
       action: function() {
          params.context.thisComponent.differentFunction(params);
       }
   }
}
```